# Get selected value of a RadSearchBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

i Bound a "RadSearchBox" with a table having two fields,"id" and "name". I am searching through name which is fine, But i want to get id of selected name. How can i do this ?

Comment: Please provide code to show how you are binding the RadSearchBox to the DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

See the OnSearch event here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/searchbox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx because you can get the data item there (eventArgs.DataItem).

Of course, you can set the DataValueField property to the desired field in the data source and simply use the e.Value property.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **DataValueField** as ID and **DataTextField** as name,

and access it in **OnSearch** event. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to accomplish this is to attach to the OnClientSearch client-event of the searchbox and pass the args.get_value() and args.get_text() values to the server with the help of a hidden field:

ASPX

```
    <asp:Button Text="Get Value" OnClick="Get_Value_Click" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField id="hiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <script>    
        function OnClientSearch(sender, args) {
            var text = args.get_text();
            var value = args.get_value();
            concatenatedValues = text + "|" + value;
            var hiddenField = $get("hiddenField1");
            hiddenField.value = concatenatedValues;
        }
    </script>
```

Codebehind

```
public RadSearchBox searchBox;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    searchBox = new RadSearchBox();
    searchBox.OnClientSearch = "OnClientSearch";
    searchBox.DataValueField = "ID";
    searchBox.DataTextField = "Name";
    searchBox.DataSource = GetSearchBoxData();
    searchBox.DataBind();

    Form.Controls.Add(searchBox);
}

protected void Get_Value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] values = hiddenField1.Value.Split('|');
    string text = values[0];
    string value = values[1];
    Response.Write("SearchBox text from hiddenField: " + text + "<br/>");
    Response.Write("SearchBox value from hiddenField: " + value + "<br/>");
}


public DataTable GetSearchBoxData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mary");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "David");

    return dt;
}
```